# Eclipse PDT - mark all occurrences of selected string (glance plugin not working)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

**Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)**

Is there any way to mark all occurrences of selected string in the document? (like Notepad++ does - clicking on the string marks all occurrences of this string in document)

**1)** I didn't find any core feature which can do this when searching similar questions (core feature can mark variables but not strings)

**2)** Seems the only solution is using a "Glance" plugin for now, but it works only some seconds/minutes for me and then it is not able to search or mark anything. See image (gif):

[image: Eclipse Glance plugin not working]

Will be great if somebody can answer:

1) if there is some other solution than glance plugin

2) or how to fix the problems with glance plugin

Thank you.

Comment: A normal Search...File would do what it sounds like you want from this Glance plugin.

Comment: I don't want to find the occurrences, I just want to mark all of them. The Glance plugin works OK until it freezes.

Comment: Did you actually try Search..**File**?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't understand what you mean with "Search..**File**"? I don't want to search the occurrences I just want to have them all marked.

Comment: The Search menu has a File option. The Search dialog also has a File tab.

Comment: Yes, I am using File search for searching items in Files, but in this case I don't want to search anything but marking occurrences I click (select) in current document.